# zipline: ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass'

Tags: python, zipline

when i import zipline, there is a error

```
/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/utils/calendars/exchange_calendar_ice.py:10: FutureWarning: The pandas.tslib module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.   from pandas.tslib import Timestamp Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import finance   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/finance/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import execution, trading   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/finance/trading.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pandas.tslib import normalize_date ImportError: cannot import name 'normalize_date'
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/1870

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?